# When I delete "Watch Me Do" from Automator, does it get deleted forever?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, automator

Is Automator's "Watch Me Do" action permanently deleted when it is removed from the action sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the changes you made being deleted (i.e., the stuff it watched you do), I expect it is permanently deleted.

The action itself (in the source list) oughtn't ever be deleted.